# How can I select multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a dataset (Rows:5000 and Columns: 60).
I want to read some of the columns which are related to my analysis but the code doesn't work.

> Column 1, column 5, columns 22 to 28 and columns 47 to 54.

I've read the manual and it seems just I can select the number of columns one by one or range not both of them. 
Could you please let me know how can I solve this problem?

```
All_Dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', engine = 'python')
data = All_Dataset.iloc[:, [0, 5,  22:29, 47:55]]
```

Comment: The package you're using (pandas as far as I can tell) is not part of python's standard library. When you have a question on a third-part package, please mention it in the tags and preferably in your question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.r_`

```
import numpy as np

df.iloc[:,np.r_[0, 5,  22:29, 47:55]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You could create a list with the indices by [chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) the iterables:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

# create sample data-frame
data = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(10, 100))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# create indices
indices = list(chain([0, 5], range(22, 29), range(47, 55)))

result = df.iloc[:, indices]
print(result.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(10, 17)
```